# Cannot draw proper route for the google maps api for android v2

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2

I am not able to draw the correct route between two places using the new version of the api?..After going through a lot of research I found that by using the polyline data out of the directions api will help me and indeed it did as I was able to draw it. But its avoiding slight turns by just adding a straight line.How can I draw a correct path?..

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr=" + source_lat
+ "," + source_lon + "&daddr=" + destination_lat + ","+ destination_lat));
                intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps",
                        "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
                ((Activity) this).startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you!...But will it make use of the new google maps api android v2.If I am not wrong this displays the google maps in a browser.Is it not so?

Comment: It does not open google map in browser,it opens in native google map app. Orelse, if you wanna display route inside your map activity then you have to go for polyline but it does not give you the actual route instead it displays a line between source and destination.